# Bouncing ball app in touch listener in android

Tags: android, touch, gesture, bounce

I refer this link [Bouncing Ball](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/bouncing-a-ball-on-androids-canvas/).When user touch on ball, it stops moving & When user release ball then it continues moving. how can we do it using touch gesture ?

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: well, that is much declarative answer than your tinny question, as equal as another tutorial.What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ridoy i try to using touch listener. but i not work done by me.Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i said earlier that is much declarative answer to help you here.You need to share your code here to help something.

I would like to give you some hint to do this: override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method. Use `event.getAction()` to catch various `MotionEvent`. When you can identify `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` then set `event.getX()` and `getY()` as your objects current **x,y**. That will stop moving your object.

Similarly, at `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` update your objects position(x,y according to the direction), and set `yourObject.setTouched(false)`. So when user release his finger from the screen object will start to move again.